# When I call execute method of CloseableHttpClient object, my program freezes

Tags: java

I have a program that polls Bitcoin price information every minute. After about 2 hours of running it will freeze.

I found out that the method `execute` of the `CloseableHttpClient` class was causing it to freeze. I found this out by putting in a lot of print statements. (The program is running within eclipse)

```
public PriceTicket[] getFirstDaysSale() throws IOException {
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Gdet first curser for price data
    HttpGet getRequest = new 
      HttpGet("https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/trades");

    System.out.print("create athentication");
    Authentication.setNonAuthenticationHeaders(getRequest);
    CloseableHttpClient temp = HttpClients.createDefault();    

    String g;
    System.out.print("Startexec");

    //PROGRAM WILL FREEZE HERE
    CloseableHttpResponse response = temp.execute(getRequest);

    System.out.print("end exec");
    Header h = response.getFirstHeader("CB-AFTER");
    nextCurId=h.getValue();
    System.out.print("create reader");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    System.out.print("create json");
    String json = processStream(br);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    PriceTicket[] priceData = gson.fromJson(json, PriceTicket[].class);
    return priceData;
}
```

Console output:

```
......
......
create athentication
Startexec
```

Program stops here

Comment: As the names state, `CloseableHttpClient` and `CloseableHttpResponse` should be closed after use. Potentially, all resources are exhausted after running for a while.

Comment: As @qqilihq pointed out, you should close both client and responses after you're done with then. Also, clients are quite expensive to create, so consider creating just one and then share it.

Comment: Where are you handling the `IOException`?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help.  I am clossing the connection. whitch helps but does not solve the issue.  It now runs for about half  day, then freezez at the same spot. I'm handling IOException in the calling methed. I'm thinking about runnin g this methed on a thread, then terminate the thread if it freezes.